# Configuring image popups in a Silverlight application

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, silverlight, attachments, arcgis-silverlight-viewer

My Silverlight application contains a points layer which contains paths to a folder of geotagged photos. These points were generated using the [GeoTagged Photos to Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000165000000) tool. I chose not to import the photos into the file gdb. When I view the layer in ArcMap and configure popups to display the path as a URL, clicking on a point pops up a preview of the image instead of the default popup (showing the actual value of the Path field).

Inside my application (built using the ArcGIS Silverlight viewer), the popups only show the path to the image. There does not seem to be an option to configure it as a link instead. In order for the actual image to be displayed, would I have to select the option to add the photos as attachments to the SDE gdb?

Comment: Are you using HTML Popups? Simply configuring it using the "As a URL" option should work (select your url field). Of course the URL schema for desktop is not equal for web applications. Using an standard publishing schema with a webserver in the middle can solve that.

Comment: I did try that option. I just wanted to know if there was an option in the Silverlight viewer to set it so that the image displays in the popup. I had to import the images as attachments so it displays at the bottom of the popup, and you have to click it to open in a new tab. What I actually want is only for the image to show in the popup. Disabling the other fields does not increase the size of the image at the bottom, it constrains it to a "thumbnail" view.